# pysocks library not supporting proxy ipv6

Tags: telethon, pysocks

pysocks library doesnt support proxy ipv6 is there any way that solve this or any other libraries ?

Im using it with telethon to interact with telegram API

Also I tried another library called python_socks same error
Any Ideas?